# Route domain to subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, routes

I have mutliple ways to access the same domain, IE:
http://staging.me.com/DOMAIN/
http://DOMAIN.com
localhost:888/domain

and I need all three of these to route to a subdirectory while I build out the new version of the site.

I have tried multiple .htaccess configurations but none seem to do the same job on all servers. Thoughts?

**current test:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /v2
```

**have tried:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?DOMAIN.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /v2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being the fix for this instance since there are so many possible type-in varities. This will be removed once the new site is up and running.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?$ %{REQUEST_URI}v2/ [L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule in your document root's .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?DOMAIN\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!v2/).*)$ /v2/$1 [L,NC]
```